Is there any direction on configuring Azure AD - the Azure setup for SAML authentication configuration on Tridion sites 9.1?
I have been trying to set up SAML authentication against Azure AD for a while now, and am not making any real progress on my own or with the RWS support. Does anyone have specific directions on configuring the Azure side of things to make this work? I am at a point where I think I have my SAML parameters set, and have run the SetupSAML script and backed out of it a couple of dozen times, but the only directions I have been able to find, and the only thing I have received from RWS support is the Velmurugan Arjunan Blog post. I still feel like I have to manually make changes to the saml config file even though the script runs without error even to get to this point for some reason. And I still am unable to sign in with Azure AD credentials. The user that shows up in the ribbon at the top of the page is "Default User" and I can never get to the point where I can sign in, and create groups to manage the actual connection and association of Azure users. The furthest I have gotten is to the point where the loading gif spins, and then I have to reload the main root path, like https://cmedomain.com/SDL/ and then I still get a 500 POST error as the auth mechanism is apparently getting hung up on going to get the user's groups maybe? at this location: https://cmedomain.com/WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/GetUserSettings
500 (System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException)
I am uncertain as to whether my Azure AD admins have configured some strange security policy that I am unaware of because I don't have enough permissions, or if there is still something on the setupSAML script side in the CME server that isn't configuring something completely correctly.
Tridion Sites 9.1 on prem servers on Windows with Java 11 and https configured

Note that Tridion Sites 9.1 is no longer supported by RWS and uses what we now call a "legacy" SAML integration.  As of Tridion Sites 9.5, we are using a new Access Management subsystem which can integrate with SAML IDPs, but preferably OpenID Connect IDPs.  So, you can still use SAML (if you really want), but the integration is done quite differently.  If the customer requirement is to integrate with a SAML/OIDC IDP, I would strongly suggest to upgrade to Tridion Sites 9.6 or later.

Right, but it's a timing thing. So, the need to upgrade to a more modern authentication mechanism is more pressing right now. But it sounds like what you're saying is no, there isn't any documentation around how to configure that.

No, I didn't mean to say there is no documentation about it, but just that you may want to prevent putting a lot of effort in a legacy feature on an unsupported version.  But if you insist: https://docs.rws.com/en-US/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1-783502/content-manager-integration-with-saml-555579
